# WaitForFirstConsumer PersistentVolumeClaim waiting for first consumer to be created before binding. Auto provisioning does not work

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, persistent-volumes

Hi I know this might be a possible duplicate, but I cannot get the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55044486/waitforfirstconsumer-persistentvolumeclaim-waiting-for-first-consumer-to-be-crea).

I have a prometheus deployment and would like to give it a persistent volume.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus-deployment
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: prometheus-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: prometheus
          image: prom/prometheus
          args:
            - "--storage.tsdb.retention.time=60d"
            - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
            - "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 500M
            limits:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 1Gi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: prometheus-config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/prometheus/
            - name: prometheus-storage-volume
              mountPath: /prometheus/
      volumes:
        - name: prometheus-config-volume
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            name: prometheus-server-conf

        - name: prometheus-storage-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: prometheus-pv-claim

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: prometheus-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: default
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
```

Now both the pvc and the deployment cannot be scheduled because the pvc waits for the deployment and the other way around. As far as I am concerned we have a cluster with automatic provisioning, thus I cannot just create a pv. How can I solve this problem, because other deployments do use pvc in the same style and it works.

Comment: Hello @msts1906 Has any answer below helped you?

Comment: Yes thank you very much. It was the namespace issue. I already accepted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of namespace. PVC is a namespaced object [you can look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364367/share-persistent-volume-claims-amongst-containers-in-kubernetes-openshift/35366775#35366775). Your PVC is on the default namespace. Moving it to monitoring namespace should work.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: prometheus-pv-claim
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  storageClassName: default
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
```

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#a-note-on-namespaces

Answer (score 0):

Does your PVC deploy the correct namespace with deployment?
And make sure the StorageClass has volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: default
...
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Comment: This is already the case. Thank you

Comment: Consider accepting the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solves your issue.